# What does the letter code on a UK biometric residence permit indicate?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, residency

What does the letter code indicated on a British Biometric Residence Permit refer to? What are the different possible codes?

Comment: Which code specifically? https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/539328/In-Country_information_leaflet_-_July_2016.pdf

Comment: @Traveller I would guess the first 2 letters of the 7th one. But purely my guess.